# Calculate a field value using other 2 fields values using onChange

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, redux-form

**The scene:**

Think about 3 fields: `quantity`, `singlePrice`, `totalPrice`.
I need all them to be fields in my form but totalPrice has to be re-calculated every time i change quantity or singlePrice with a simple operation that you can imagine..

**What I did:**

- created a function triggered by the onChange event of the quantity field and another one for the singlePrice field.
- the above function calls a redux action with a payload like this:

  `{ name: name_of_the_updated_field, value: new_field_value }`
- that action is picked up by a [formReducer plugin](http://redux-form.com/6.6.0/docs/api/ReducerPlugin.md/) that makes the calculations and return the updated value object.

**The Problem:**
My redux store is not updated nor my form is.

**My form reducer** (the property I have to update is inside another property).

```
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form';

export default formReducer.plugin({
  formName: (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'CALC_TOTAL_PRICE':
        return {
          ...state,
          values: {
            ...state.values,
            competences: state.values.competences.map((c, i) => {
              if (i === action.payload.index) {
                const { name, value } = action.payload;
                const next = Object.assign({}, c);
                next[name] = value;
                next.totalPrice = next.quantity * next.singlePrice
                return next;
              }
              return c;
            }),
          },
        };
      default:
        return state;
    }
  },
});
```

Am I missing something? How to fix this? 
Is a simpler way to have this result?

Any help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You might think to use `formValueSelector` to get the present input value and calculate total something like-

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm, formValueSelector, FieldArray, SubmissionError } from 'redux-form';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class NewSaleForm extends React.Component {

   componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
      if (nextProps.items && nextProps.items.length > 0) {
         nextProps.items.forEach((item) => {
            if (item.price && item.unit) {
               if (item.unit_discount) {
                  item.total = (item.price - item.unit_discount) * item.unit;
               } else {
                  item.total = item.price * item.unit;
               }
            } else {
               item.total = '';
            }
         });
      }
   }

render() {
   ......
}


NewSaleForm = reduxForm({ // eslint-disable-line
   form: 'newSaleForm'
})(NewSaleForm);

const selector = formValueSelector('newSaleForm');

NewSaleForm = connect(state => { // eslint-disable-line
   const items = selector(state, 'items');
   return {
      items,
   };
})(NewSaleForm);

export default NewSaleForm;
```

Comment: Fazal Rasel, thanks for your response! I understand what you mean but maybe I wasn't clear in my explanation: I should somehow inject data into the `fields` property of the `FieldArray` because I already have data to fit into the form fields, after I selected an object from a select.
This is a 'working' esample.. may I ask you to suggest me how to fix it?

https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-Kecgj77Gbxo_4am3WS1
when you select a product from the select it should give the data to the fields quite like the FIeldsArray example